# Html Agility Pack vs. 302 redirects to same page

Tags: redirect, html-agility-pack, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to pick up meta tags from the old http://www.printprint.ca site at 108.170.59.213 (I have this in my hosts file), but can't seem to get anything in DocumentNode. 
The old site seems to 302 redirect to the same page, and it breaks all crawlers like Xenu, ScreamingFrog, BeamUsUp...
After inital 302 to same page it responds with 200 but I don't know how to make HtmlAgilityPack pick up on that.
I've tried adding this:

```
web.PreRequest = OnPreRequest;

private static bool OnPreRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this old. But since there is no answer I might input my solution.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.printprint.ca ");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "text/html;charset=utf-8";

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {

            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                doc.Load(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    HtmlNodeCollection metas = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//meta");
    foreach(HtmlNode meta in metas)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(meta.OuterHtml);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```